# Dialog Flow Response: actions On google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a response which has Simple Response with a BasicCard.The response from dialogflow to Google assistant is like this:

```
"payload": {
        "google": {
            "expectUserResponse": true,
            "richResponse": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "simpleResponse": {
                            "textToSpeech": "Can you tell your TV's model number? (Eg. 42PFL7008S/12)",
                            "displayText": "Can you tell your TV's model number? (Eg. 42PFL7008S/12)"
                        },
                        "basicCard": {
                            "image": {
                                "url": "https://",
                                "accessibilityText": "The model number can be found here "
                            },
                            "title": "The model number can be found on here,
                            "subtitle": "It is also called Set-Type,"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "suggestions": []
            }
        }
    }
```

In the response GA, Simulator I am getting the following error:

```
expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt: the first element must be a 'simple_response', a 'structured_response' or a 'custom_response'.
```

GA response i dont see the simple response in the simulator..Somewhere the simple response is discarded..Is there any flaw in this response from DialogFlow?

Comment: Are you using code to define responses ?

Comment: You say you don't see the simple response in the simulator. Can you update your question to include the entire response from the simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that each object in the `items[]` array is supposed to have a single field which indicates what the type of the item is. So one item will have a `simpleResponse` attribute with corresponding values. Another item will have a `basicCard` attribute, with all the values for it.

You seem to have a single object in the `items[]` array with two attributes, `simpleResponse` and `basicCard`. Split them up into two objects in the array. Something like this:

```
                "items": [
                    {
                        "simpleResponse": {
                            "textToSpeech": "Can you tell your TV's model number? (Eg. 42PFL7008S/12)",
                            "displayText": "Can you tell your TV's model number? (Eg. 42PFL7008S/12)"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "basicCard": {
                            "image": {
                                "url": "https://",
                                "accessibilityText": "The model number can be found here "
                            },
                            "title": "The model number can be found on here,
                            "subtitle": "It is also called Set-Type,"
                        }
                    }
                ],
```